# c# asp.net cannot get posted files

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi i am using this [tutorial](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Uploading-Multiple-Files-using-FileUpload-Control-in-ASPNet-20-30-and-35.aspx) to try and upload up to 5 files while using the exact code from the tutorial it worked as expected. now i got tempted to develop a web app to store the content of pdf files on my elasticsearch i thought that giving it a proper design is the way to go and used some pre designed bootstrap templates and also i added some text fields and get the value trough `request["textfield"]` now i am aware that the bootsrap is heavily nested with divs. upon executing the code behind see below i noticed that the files were not saved now my question is the code behind would have difficulty finding the posted files with bootstrap templates vs that of the tutorial

thanks

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile PostedFile = Request.Files[i];
        if (PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
            PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files\\") + FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is sent to the server has nothing at all to do with bootstrap templates or structure. Show us the actual problem using a [mcve]

Comment: As long as file posted correctly as part of request payload, server code should be able to find it. How you are trying to post with bootstrap template/html/client script, is equally important to understand your problem.

Comment: Client side and server side components are totally different entities. Bootstrap i.e. a third party css library knows absolutely nothing about the server. The only time you should be concerned with whats on the client side is where you need to use ajax (or equivalent) to post a request to the server.

Comment: Can you use your browser dev tools and show us the `POST` that is occurring (screenshot, or preferably text)?